# RPA BluePrism Excel VBO Extended

Tags: excel, blueprism, rpa

I am trying to create a excel VBO action in BluePrism which can find text in excel and return cell value

```
Dim excel as Object = GetInstance(handle)
Dim strText as String = Text
Dim ws as Object
ws = GetWorksheet( _
     handle, workbook_name, worksheet_name, False)
Dim r as Object
r = ws.Range("1:1")
r.Activate()
Dim cell as Object = excel.ActiveCell
Dim s as Object
s = ws.Cells.Find(What:=[Text], After:=cell, _
Lookin:="xlWhole", SearchOrder:="xlByColumns", SearchDirection:="xlNext", _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
s.Activate()
cellref = ws.ActiveCell.Address(False,False)
```

This fails at find function with error index mismatch. I am not sure what is going wrong here

Basically I am doing this as I have huge files in which I have to search certain value and extract few lines above and below the found value. When I try to get worksheet as collection, it fails with 'out of memory' exception.

Is there a way to do this using existing VBOs ? If not Could anyone help me write the VBO to find text in excel ?

Answer (score 1):

If `GetHandle()` fails, it means the Excel instance described by the `handle` value you're passing doesn't exist.

Either use the same instance of the Excel VBO to launch an instance of MS Excel, or Attach to an existing one and get a separate `handle` value for the new VBO. `handle`s are not transferable between instances/copies of the VBO.

Answer (score 0):

I've got nice and tidy excel's method Find() implemented in my environment. I hope that's enough to get you going.

```
dim nLookin as long
if LookIn = "xlFormulas" then
    nLookIn = -4123
elseif LookIn = "xlValues" then
    nLookIn = -4163
elseif LookIn = "xlComments" then
    nLookIn = -4144 
else
    Throw New System.Exception("Incorrect parameter passed for LookIn")
end if

dim nLookAt as long
if LookAt = "xlPart" then
    nLookAt = 2
elseif LookAt = "xlWhole" then
    nLookAt = 1
else
    Throw New System.Exception("Incorrect parameter passed for LookAt")
end if

dim nSearchDirection as long
if SearchDirection = "xlNext" then
    nSearchDirection = 1
elseif SearchDirection = "xlPrevious" then
    nSearchDirection = 2
else
    Throw New System.Exception("Incorrect parameter passed for SearchDirection")
end if

dim oWS as object
dim oResult as object
oWS = GetWorksheet(Handle,nWB,nWS, False)


oResult = oWS.Range(nR).Find(what:=Value, LookIn:=nLookin, MatchCase:=MatchCase, LookAt:=nLookAt, SearchDirection:=nSearchDirection)


if oResult is nothing then
    Address = "Not found"
    Column = "A"
    Row = 1
else
    Address = oResult.address
    'Convert_to_Letter(oResult.Column, Column)
    Row = oResult.Row
End If

oWS = nothing
oResult = nothing
```

[image: Parameters used]